# How to send STDIN(multiple arguments) to external process and work within interactive mode

Tags: perl

External program has interactive mode asking for some details. Each passed argument must be accepted by return key. So far I managed to pass an argument to external process however the problem I'm facing more then one argument is passed, perl executes then all when you close pipe.
It's impractical in interactive modes when arguments are passed one by one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open2;

open(HANDLE, "|cmd|");
print HANDLE "time /T\n";
print HANDLE "date /T\n";
print HANDLE "dir\n";
close HANDLE;
```

Comment: Enable autoflush on the write end of the pipe to the external process. If you were actually using `IPC::Open2` the right way, this would be done for you.

Comment: @mob Instead of pointing out that the code is wrong, they already know it doesn't work, you should step up with an answer showing "the right way"?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't pass double pipes into `open` as one would like, and loading [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen2) doesn't fix that.  You have to use the `open2` function exported by IPC::Open2.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open2;
use IO::Handle;  # so we can call methods on filehandles

my $command = 'cat';
open2( my $out, my $in, $command ) or die "Can't open $command: $!";

# Set both filehandles to print immediately and not wait for a newline.
# Just a good idea to prevent hanging.
$out->autoflush(1);
$in->autoflush(1);

# Send lines to the command
print $in "Something\n";
print $in "Something else\n";

# Close input to the command so it knows nothing more is coming.
# If you don't do this, you risk hanging reading the output.
# The command thinks there could be more input and will not
# send an end-of-file.
close $in;

# Read all the output
print <$out>;

# Close the output so the command process shuts down
close $out;
```

This pattern works if all you have to do is send a command a bunch of lines and then read the output once.  If you need to be interactive, it's very very easy for your program to hang waiting for output that is never coming.  For interactive work, I would suggest [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun).  It's rather overpowered, but it will cover just about everything you might want to do with an external process.

Comment: No sure why you said that the code I used doesn't work. It works OK with AUTOFLUSH.

Comment: your code doesn't seem to work at all. My problem is also that IPC:Run is not available for perl for windows

Comment: @jey I say the code you used doesn't work because `open(HANDLE, "|cmd|")` produces the warning "Can't open bidirectional pipe".  If your code works then it's not the same as the code you posted.  IPC::Run is available on Windows, but you'll have to install it like any other CPAN module.  How do you mean my code doesn't work?  Are you getting an error message?  Is it completely silent?  Does it sit around on the couch all day and drink all the milk?